# Why do veterinary vaccines have shorter effect?

Tags: immunology, vaccination, feline

In humans activated T-lymphocytes persist until end of life, and activated B-lymphocytes persist many years, so most vaccines don't need to be reapplied and the few that do are reapplied after 10 to 15 years (recommendation varies slightly by country).

However cats (and dogs) are vaccinated every year, with individual vaccines reapplied after one, two or three years.

Does the immune system of cats differ so that it loses the activated lymphocytes faster? Or why are the vaccines (recommended to be) reapplied so often?

Comment: Can you give an example of *the same* vaccine that is recommended every year for dogs/cats but only every 10-15 years for humans?

Comment: I get an influenza vaccine every year, and now expect to get a COVID booster after 6 months.  Tetanus is 10 years, or if you have a wound that might result in an infection.  (I'm human, BTW :-))  Perhaps one reason canine vaccines are given more often is that your dog can't really tell you when s/he's sick, until it's too late.  Some are for things that are invariably fatal and/or easily transmitted, like rabies.  So perhaps one factor is "better safe than sorry".

Comment: @jamesqf, Influenza is a different vaccine every year. Tetanus is bacterial, so 10 (but it's 15 here) years make sense as it relies on B-lymphocytes only. What's going on with the covid one is not yet understood, so I'd leave it out for now.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately rabies vaccines decline in effectiveness over time.

The first key study was by HN Johnson in 1954. He tested 25 dogs 1 and 2 years after receiving a vaccine. The dogs in the control group all died. The dogs inoculated at 1 year had a 100% survival rate. The dogs challenged with rabies at 2 years had an 88% survival rate. So, apparently there was some degredation in the vaccine effectiveness after a year.

Rabies vaccine duration effectiveness was also studied in the following experiment:

Dodds WJ, Larson LJ, Christine KL, Schultz RD. Duration of immunity after rabies vaccination in dogs: The Rabies Challenge Fund research study. Can J Vet Res. 2020;84(2):153-158.

In this study the effectiveness of the vaccine declined over time. All of the beagles in the control group died. In the 6 year group, survival was 80%, but it dropped to 50% in the 7 year group and only 20% in the 8 year group.

So, given these kinds of numbers the tendency has been to try to do an annual vaccination to maximize the level of protection.

Comment: But is there any idea of the underlying mechanism *why* that happens?

Comment: @JanHudec According to current knowledge, the only long-lived immunological cells are long-lived bone marrow plasma cells which can drip out serum antibodies for years unlike other immunological cells which are mostly dead after a month or two. So, if a vaccine loses effectiveness over the course of years, the only apparent cause would be a gradual decline in bone marrow plasma cells which are producing rabies antibodies.

Comment: And memory T cells, no? Those should be even longer lived given thymus shrinks with age. And the question than basically boils down to how long do the two kinds of memory cells live in carnivores.